# Filter Information from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

heys I Have some troubles with a function that has to filter information from a matrix that has some data.

first the data have multiple columns so I filter them to the years that is the information that I need and how many times a number repeats itself on it.

second I have two parameters that are two years and this is for filtering and selecting the information that the user needs so here is the problem I don't know how to cut the years that I don't want and show them on a linear graph.

here is the Code

```
def crear_grafico (lim_up:int, lim_donw:int, datos: pd.DataFrame):
    
    lista_años = []
    
    convertir_str = ""
    
    año_analizado = lim_infe 
    while año_analizado <=lim_sup:
        convertir_str =  str(año_analizado)
        lista_años.append(convertir_str)
        
        año_analizado +=1
    
    #######
    #######
    #######
    columna = ['AnioDesmovilizacion']
    grupo_año =  datos[columna]
    
    grupo_año = grupo_año.value_counts()
    
    print(grupo_año)
    
    grupo_año.keys()
    print(grupo_año.keys())
```

Comment: Some parts of your code  seem irrelevant to the question. You may cut those and simplify the question for clarity. Also it would be helpful if you can show a snapshot of a part of the data or column that you're referring to, and explain your problem using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out rows for which the "year" value does not meet your desired conditions (see some examples below).

```
#If you don't want to keep rows where 'year' is '2000'
dataFiltered = data.loc[data["year"] != 2000]
```

or another example can be

```
dataFiltered = data.loc[(data["year"] > 2000) & (data["year"] != 2010)]
```